# Which is the best platform to create web applications which includes image processing algorithms?

Tags: asp.net, web

I need to create a web application that will have image processing algorithms and which deals with pixels

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend python with opencv on Apache server

you can access documentation about python web programming [here](https://realpython.com/tutorials/web-dev/)

and about opencv with python [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

and for a webserver you could use [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/)

Comment: Is there any way i can use Asp.net ?